# Do we say "the police found many ivories in the bag"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [i‧vo‧ry](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/ivory) /ˈaɪvəri/ ●○○ noun (plural ivories)
>
> 1 [uncountable] the hard smooth yellowish-white substance from the
>   tusks (=long teeth) of an elephant
>
> an ivory chess set
>
> 2 [uncountable] a yellowish-white colour
>
> an ivory silk wedding gown
>
> 3 [countable often plural] something made of ivory, especially a small
>   figure of a person or animal
>
> a collection of ivories

Is it ok to say "**This elephant has 2 ivories**" or "**This elephant has 2 ivory tusks**"?

Also, do we say "**the police found many ivories in the bag**" or "**the police found many ivory tusks in the bag**" (see the picture)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All elephant's tusks are of ivory, so referring to them, I would just say "elephant tusks".

If a smuggler had a bag of elephant tusks, one could say that he was smuggling ivory.

I wouldn't say "an elephant has two ivories".

I think all elephants have two tusks, unless they have lost one or both, so I wouldn't say "This elephant has two ivory tusks". It's like saying "this elephant has a trunk".